# Should I use an article in this sentence

Tags: articles

I wrote:

> In addition, the user can declare and set (the /some / ) context variables in each rule.

Do I need to use an article here?

Comment: An article is not needed there.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need an article. The sentence doesn't qualify *context variables*; we don't know which ones or how many are settable. Because of this, it's not appropriate to add an article, as they're used to specify nouns; for example:

- *the context variables* - all of them
- *some context variables* - we don't know exactly which ones, but more than one and less than all
- *a context variable* - exactly one, but we don't know which
- *the context variable* - exactly one, and we know which particular one it is, because it was specified earlier